# Order of traversal given by std::filesystem directory_iterator

Tags: c++

When iterating through a directory using `std::filesystem::directory_iterator`, are there any guarantees regarding the order of traversal?

Comment: Documentation...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order is unspecified per [[fs.class.directory.iterator]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/fs.class.directory.iterator#8)

> The order of directory entries obtained by dereferencing successive increments of a `directory_­iterator` is unspecified.

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator):

> The iteration order is **unspecified**, except that each directory entry
>   is visited only once. The special pathnames dot and dot-dot are
>   skipped.